# Servicio WCF se detiene despues de un tiempo

Tags: webservice, iis, wcf

Estimados, tengo una aplicacion en c#, wcf hosteado en un server donde no tengo acceso al IIS (por el tipo de plan contratado, es en donweb). El tema es que pasado un tiempo el servicio se cae, pensé que era por la configuración del ApplicationSpool, el tiempo de inactividad que por default es de 20min …pero no parece ser eso, hice una aplicación cliente que cada 10 min abre el servicio consume un método y trae datos solo para tratar de mantener vivo el servicio pero llega a 1 hora y vuelve a caer…no parece ser el tiempo de inactividad….alguien se le ocurre que puede ser?.

El desarrollo es una aplicación wcf configurado como wshttpbinding, puedo pasar detalles del web.config y configuración del svc

Desde ya agradezco cualquier ayuda

Saludos, Pablo

Comment: ¿qué es exactamente lo que _cae_? ¿tienes acceso a los logs? ¿genera tu aplicación un log?

Comment: "*el tiempo de inactividad que por default es de 20min …pero no parece ser eso*" <-- ¿por qué? ¿qué te lleva a descartarlo?

Comment: jachguate descarto los 20 minutos por inactividad por que hice una aplicacion de consola que se conecta al servicio usa un metodo y cierra el servicio cada 10 minutos....por inactividad no deberia ser... pero estuve investigando un poco mas y puede ser que sea el proceso de reciclado., el problema es que el servicio de hosting que tengo contratado no me dejan hacer modificaciones en el IIS....